# ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar not showing message on screen

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display a message to the user on the login screen when they type in either a bad email or a bad password.

I am using the Google email and password login with Cloud Firestore.

Here is the code for the Login button:

```
TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {

                        await getCurrentUserName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "invalid-credential":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Wrong email or password. Please try again";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
```

At the bottom of the code is where I try to show the error message. When I go through the code in debug mode everything works but no message shows.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I made the changes to my code to follow more of what you suggested. Here is the new code:

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {    
                        await getCurrentUserName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (error) {
                      if (error is FirebaseAuthException) {
                        //} on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                        switch (error.code) {
                          case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                          case "invalid-email":
                            errorMessage =
                                "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                            break;
                          case "invalid-credential":
                            errorMessage =
                                "Wrong email or password. Please try again";
                            break;
                          case "email-already-in-use":
                            errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                            break;
                          case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                          case "wrong-password":
                            errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                            break;
                          case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                          case "user-not-found":
                            errorMessage =
                                "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                            break;
                          case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                          case "user-disabled":
                            errorMessage =
                                "User with this email has been disabled.";
                            break;
                          case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                          case "too-many-requests":
                            errorMessage =
                                "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                            break;
                          case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                          case "operation-not-allowed":
                            errorMessage =
                                "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                            break;
                          default:
                            errorMessage =
                                "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                        }
                      } else {
                        errorMessage = error.toString();
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 15),
                  )),
```

I also changed it to an Eleveated Button but that shouldn't make a difference.

I am still getting the same result, nothing is displayed on an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      String errorMessage = "";
      try {
        //yourCode
      } catch (error) {
        if (error is FirebaseAuthException) {
          switch (error.code) {
            // Your Swtich Case Code
          }
        } else {
          errorMessage = error.toString();
        }
        if (errorMessage != "") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))),
          );
        }
      }
```

This might help you understand what errors you are getting. Will trigger the snack bar if there is an error.
Later on, you can adjust your Switch to trigger the snack bar better.
what you are doing wrong is trying to catch the FirebaseAuthException and ignoring any other exception. In your case, the exception may not be of the type FirebaseAuthException. thus not triggering the snackbar.

Comment: I made changes to the code that are more in line with your suggestion. However, the Snackbar code still runs but the snackbar does not show up on the screen.

Comment: I just realized that the snackbar is displaying but the keyboard is covering it so I need to hide the keyboard.